# Move data from Opeansearch to Dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, opensearch

As a total AWS noobs, I was wondering if there is a way to “migrate” all the existing data from OpenSearch to DynamoDB?

AS we need storing rather than fast querying, we have been thinking to migrate to DynamoDB. Are there any best practices that could be followed to prevent any future problems?

Comment: You do understand what a DynamoDB is?? It will be a key-value store, you cannot "search" through it.

Comment: I know we don't want to search functionality anymore and want to use the DynamoDB for storage, :) thus we want to migrate the opensearch data to DynamoDB

Comment: I havent tried this but this might help ; you can backup your OpenSearch data to s3 and then from s3 you can import it to dynamodb.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/managedomains-snapshots.html

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/amazon-dynamodb-can-now-import-amazon-s3-data-into-a-new-table/

Comment: You cannot use an Opensearch snapshot as source for DynamoDB S3 Import.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how much data you have in Opensearch.

If you have a small amount of data, you can use **Lambda** or **EC2**.

If you have large amounts of data then use:

##### [AWS Glue](https://aws.amazon.com/glue/)

AWS Glue has a connector for both [DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect.html#aws-glue-programming-etl-connect-dynamodb) and [Opensearch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/ug/tutorial-elastisearch-connector.html) which makes reading from one and writing to another really simple.

Comment: Thanks for commenting and providing this info, I will look into AWS Glue. :)  
But would you please care to explain why one can not simply use an Opensearch snapshot as source for DynamoDB S3 Import?!.

Comment: DynamoDB import from S3 requires data to be in DDB-JSON, ION or CSV format. Which an Opensearch snapshot is not.